# How to insert moving menu bar in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, menubar

How can I get the menu bar like on this page http://eddieringle.com/ at the top of the page. A menu bar that would move along when I scroll down the page. The black bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not moving, it just a div fixed into place. From the site in question.

```
#topbar {
left: 0;
position: fixed;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: url(../images/topbar-bg.png) repeat-x 50% 100%;
z-index: 900;
padding: 5px 0 19px;
}
```